# The default [NSTableViewDelegate tableView:sizeToFitWidthOfColumn:] doesn't get called

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

According to [Apple's documentation on `[NSTableViewDelegate tableView:sizeToFitWidthOfColumn:]`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:sizeToFitWidthOfColumn:):

> By default, NSTableView iterates every row in the table, accesses a
>   cell via preparedCellAtColumn:row:, and requests the cellSize to find
>   the appropriate largest width to use.
>
> For accurate results and performance, it’s recommended that this
>   method is implemented when using large tables. By default, large
>   tables use a monte carlo simulation instead of iterating every row.

This *default* behavior is exactly what I want, so I choose not to implement this method in my NSTableViewDelegate. However, when I double click a column’s resize divider, nothing happens. My table view is view-based.

Answer (score 4):

As of OS X 10.10.2, columns in view-based table views still do not auto-size when double-clicking the column separator.

I implemented the delegate to sample rows of the visible rect as well as 50 rows below and above.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView sizeToFitWidthOfColumn:(NSInteger)column
{
    // Note: Called on double-click of table columns separator
    // Note: As of 10.10.2, [NSTableView _sizeToFitWidthOfColumn] does nothing for view-based table views
    NSRect          visibleRect     = tableView.visibleRect;
    NSRange         rowRange        = [tableView rowsInRect:visibleRect];
    NSUInteger      numberOfRows    = tableView.numberOfRows;
    NSInteger       minRow          = rowRange.location;
    NSInteger       maxRow          = rowRange.location + rowRange.length;

    minRow  = MAX(0, minRow - 50);
    maxRow  = MIN(numberOfRows, maxRow + 50);

    NSTableColumn   *tableColumn    = [[tableView tableColumns] objectAtIndex:column];
    CGFloat         minWidth        = tableColumn.minWidth;
    CGFloat         maxWidth        = tableColumn.maxWidth;
    CGFloat         width           = minWidth;

    /*
     NSCell         *headerCell     = tableColumn.headerCell;

     if ([headerCell isKindOfClass:[NSCell class]]) {
        NSRect  bounds          = NSMakeRect(0.0f, 0.0f, maxWidth, headerCell.cellSize.height);
        CGFloat fittingWidth    = [headerCell cellSizeForBounds:bounds].width;

        if (fittingWidth > width) {
            width = fittingWidth;
        }
     }
     */
    for (NSInteger row = minRow; row < maxRow; row++) {
        NSTableCellView *tableCellView  = [tableView viewAtColumn:column row:row makeIfNecessary:YES];
        CGFloat         fittingWidth    = [tableCellView fittingSize].width;

        if (fittingWidth > width) {
            width = fittingWidth;

            if (width >= maxWidth) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return MIN(maxWidth, width);
}
```